# How search for specific text in two columns with multiple criteria and with possibly more than one instance of key field?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to check for specific text in one of two columns. To make matters more complicated, it also needs to match certain additional criteria contained in 3 columns, and there may be multiple instances of the key field within the results any of which may contain the specified text and needs to return a true value.

I have tried numerous approaches and cant get anything to work. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated...

Sample sheet is attached...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LSxH1Qg_jqayakBPuTHKDB9PrinuQYcIyzjxBb9NsHY/edit#gid=615987448

Comment: can you put some desired results in column G so that we know what we're aiming at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete D4 and in A4 use:

```
=FILTER({'Report Summary'!A15:C, 'Report Summary'!F15:F}, 'Report Summary'!$C$15:$C="MET")
```

[image: 0]

---

in F4 try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A4:A="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(D4:D), "mentor"), "yes", "no")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you so much your formula works!

Also, didn't know you could do non-contiguous columns with the filter function. Something else to add to my arsenal.

Is there any way to use checkboxes for these dynamic results?

Comment: Also, could you explain your formula to me? I understand the isblank condition, and I  understand the regexmatch function but why put the regexmatch in the false condition in the if statement?

Comment: because there are two IFs. inner one deals with regexmatch and outputs true if found and false if not found. based on image, row 22 is empty so if search word isn't on row 22 (and onwards) then inner IF will put false on that row so we use outer IF to clear such row simply by checking if A22 is empty or not. eg. if A4:A is empty then output nothing (true part of IF) and if A4:A isn't empty output 2nd IF (false part of 1st IF)

Comment: cool..so you can use a blank not ""...another thing i didn't know! 

Any way to do dynamic checkboxes in the PM column instead of yes/no or TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: I just realised there was a mistake in the original sheet. There are 2 columns of data to check against not just one! How about now? (sheet has been updated)

Comment: I tried to adjust the formula you gave by saying (lower(d4:e),"mentor) but that doesn't work see row 10

Comment: nah, in that case it needs to be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A4:A="",,IF((REGEXMATCH(LOWER(D4:D), "mentor"))+(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(E4:E), "mentor")), TRUE)))` see your sheet

Comment: Thanks mate, you're a life saver. Any way to get the checkboxes working?

Comment: So, instead of using checkboxes - simply use the designated characters (because read only)! Very clever :D. Thank you